# MongoDB export to CSV

Tags: mongodb

I have met small problem, I don't know exactly where I was wrong..>.<, I want to export all data to CSV File, seem I cannot export, maybe a syntax error :(

This I my mongo data

```
"wfm_voteLog" : 
    { 
        "wfm_test@abc_com" : 
            { 
                "className" : "com.abc.com.shared.activiti.ProcessApproval", 
                "approver" : "wfm.test@abc.com", 
                "approvalTime" : ISODate("2012-08-16T08:59:43.297Z"), 
                approvalState" : "APPROVED" 
            } 
    }
```

and this my my export query

```
$ mongoexport.exe --db wfm --collection AuditTrail --csv -fields
  variables.wfm_voteLog.className
```

I believe the problem come from `"wfm_test@abc_com"`, but I dont know how to bypass this field.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: nothing in my csv file, only has a header and no content...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't do that with *mongoExport*.

```
mongoexport.exe --db wfm --collection AuditTrail --csv -fields variables.wfm_voteLog.0.className
```

This will output all the rows of your `AuditTrail` collection, and for each row/document it will put the `className` propery **only of the first** *wfm_voteLog*.

The problem here is that mongoexport doesn't extract the array from your Document. It will export only one value for each Document

you can only do some ugly things like:

```
mongoexport.exe --db wfm --collection AuditTrail --csv -fields 'variables.wfm_voteLog.0.className,variables.wfm_voteLog.1.className,variables.wfm_voteLog.2.className,...'
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues:

1. with your example document the export command fields option is incorrect, it should look like this:

   ```
   mongoexport --db wfm --collection AuditTrail --csv --fields "wfm_voteLog.wfm_test@abc_com.className"
   ```
2. There is a bug in the mongoexport parsing of field names.  The regex it uses does not match mongo's notion of proper field names.  Specifically it uses `\w` which does not include the `@` character.  If you use the `--fieldFile` option as suggested by Madarco, you can avoid this bug.

   ```
   echo wfm_voteLog.wfm_test@abc_com.className > ff;
   mongoexport --db wfm --collection AuditTrail --csv --fieldFile ff
   ```
3. Finally, the `wfm_test@abc_com` looks to me like a data value not a data model name like `emailAddress`.  I'm presuming here, that different documents would have different values here depending on the user's email. While valid mongo field names, this makes queries and your export difficult because there is no wild card for a field name.  That is, you cannot use `wfm_voteLog.*.className`. You might consider refactoring your data model.